# Building docker image with package from private nuget feed fails

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio, nuget, devextreme

I'm using the default Dockerfile generated by Visual Studio 2022 for my .NET Core 6 razor pages app. The app is using DevExpress ASP.NET Core Controls. I downloaded the necessary packages using the private Nuget feed URL supplied by the package vendor.

This is how the `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["NuGet.Config", "."]
COPY ["DMS.Monitor/DMS.Monitor.csproj", "DMS.Monitor/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DMS.Monitor/DMS.Monitor.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DMS.Monitor"
RUN dotnet build "DMS.Monitor.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DMS.Monitor.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DMS.Monitor.dll"]
```

When I try to build the image I get the following error:

> #13 [build 5/8] RUN dotnet restore "DMS.Monitor/DMS.Monitor.csproj"
> #13 sha256:f1029f328e1221cc75d3cbca3603f770dbb670711688ac30334449923e9ceb3f
> #13 0.893   Determining projects to restore...  #13 106.8 /src/DMS.Monitor/DMS.Monitor.csproj : error NU1102: Unable to find
> package DevExtreme.AspNet.Core with version (>= 21.2.8)  #13 106.8
> /src/DMS.Monitor/DMS.Monitor.csproj : error NU1102:   - Found 3
> version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 20.1.3 ]  #13 107.1
> Failed to restore /src/DMS.Monitor/DMS.Monitor.csproj (in 1.77 min).
> #13 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "DMS.Monitor/DMS.Monitor.csproj"]: exit code: 1

My project uses DevExtreme.AspNet.Core v.21.2.8 which is obviously not available in  nuget.org. Is there a way I can edit the `NuGet.Config` file to tell Docker where it can find the correct version of the package?

Comment: Hi, any update about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add your private feed using the command

```
dotnet nuget add source <package source>
```

Place it before the `dotnet restore` command in your Dockerfile.